# I run 40 hours a week? (or) I run 40 hours per week?

Tags: grammar

I run 40 hours a week?

or

I run 40 hours per week?

---

[h/week] - hours a week

or

[h/week] - hours per week

Which one is "more" grammatically correct. I often see both of them being used.

Comment: 'Each' and 'every' may be more usual. Try Google Ngrams to compare "run ten hours xxx week".

Comment: Generally 'grammatical correctness' isn't exclusively one thing.  It depends on the situation and formality as to what is more appropriate, rather than 'grammatically correct'

Comment: If you're giving a rough estimate it's "a".  If you carefully log your running time it's "per".  The two convey slightly different senses along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are grammatically equally correct. Indeed they are grammatically identical, since they differ only in one word and the word in each case is a preposition.

*Per* is perhaps slightly more formal than *a* in this sense, if only by acquiring a vague sense of being more formal by being a post-Norman addition to the language, but they are still both correct.

Answer (score 0):

Although both are probably equally correct, I think in science-related contexts, *per* would, in my opinion, be more frequent. If I were setting a physics assignment paper where this comes up, it would most likely be hours per week.